# Change the color of all nodes in a scene?

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

So this may seem like a stupid question; however, I'll see if anyone has an answer.

Is there any way to change the color of all nodes in a scene in swift? For example invert all the colors?

I've created a game using SpriteKit and would like to create different themes. Instead of changing every node one by one. I would like to at least do most in one shot. If anyone has any advice that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

-Matt

Comment: i updated the code in my answer to fix a small bug that was pointed out to me.

Comment: haha, i fixed another bug. i messed up a lot for only a few lines of code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the scene you want,

```
for node in self.children {
 // I used spritenode, but you can add as many nodes with color options as you like.
  guard let snode = node as? SKSpriteNode else { continue }
  snode.color = .blue
}
```

The inversion function would be a separate question I think :P but something like:

```
if snode.color == .black { node.color == .white }
```

But you could probably do this with RGB and math as well.

Comment: `SKNode` does not have a `color` property.

Comment: Perfect this is what I needed!

Comment: It's wrong to return on guard fail, you should use the continue statement instead.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri agreed. I would use an `if` statement.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri thanks i fixed it. need to not post before bed!!

Comment: @0x141E Ramy meant that i needed to continue not return, not to use if instead of guard :P